# Reading a null-terminated string

Tags: c#

I am reading strings from a binary file. Each string is null-terminated. Encoding is UTF-8. In python I simply read a byte, check if it's 0, append it to a byte array, and continue reading bytes until I see a 0. Then I convert byte array into a string and move on. All of the strings were read correctly.

How can I read this in C#? I don't think I have the luxury of simply appending bytes to an array since the arrays are fixed size.

Comment: Why not just append them to a string as chars?

Comment: This would work, but will use more memory than you would think.  C# strings are immutable, so each time you modify one a new string must be created.  The amount of extra memory is probably not an issue in most cases, but the best way is probably Mike's suggestion, with a sensible initial size.  List<T> is still just a wrapper around an array, which creates larger arrays when needed.

Comment: List<byte> doesn't seem too bad I guess. It sounds like the same idea as python's list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a [`List<byte>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
while(reading){ //or whatever your condition is
    list.add(readByte);
}

string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(list.ToArray());
```

Or you could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

while(reading){
    builder.Append(readByte);
}

string output = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: -1: The StringBuilder will not [append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86yy043k.aspx) the byte's character value, but the byte's integer value instead.

Comment: ReadChar() would solve that:  char c = reader.ReadChar(); builder.Append(c);

Answer (score 8):

Following should get you what you are looking for. All of text should be inside myText list.

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes("myfile.bin");
List<string> myText = new List<string>();
int lastOffset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    if (data[i] == 0)
    {
        myText.Add(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, lastOffset, i - lastOffset));
        lastOffset = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using a StreamReader instance:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using(StreamReader rdr = OpenReader(...)) {
    Int32 nc;
    while((nc = rdr.Read()) != -1) {
          Char c = (Char)nc;
          if( c != '\0' ) sb.Append( c );
    }
}
```

Comment: I like where I think you were going with this (long ago), but I think you may have (explicitly) assumed too much, so see my expanded answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your "binary file" only contains null terminated UTF8 strings, then for .NET it isn't a "binary file" but just a text file because null characters are characters too.  So you could just use a StreamReader to read the text and split it on the null characters.
(Six years later "you" would presumably be some new reader and not the OP.)

A one line (ish) solution would be:

```
using (var rdr = new StreamReader(path))
    return rdr.ReadToEnd().split(new char[] { '\0' });
```

But that will give you a trailing empty string if the last string in the file was "properly" terminated.

A more verbose solution that might perform differently for very large files, expressed as an extension method on StreamReader, would be:

```
List<string> ReadAllNullTerminated(this System.IO.StreamReader rdr)
{
    var stringsRead = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    var bldr = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    int nc;
    while ((nc = rdr.Read()) != -1)
    {
        Char c = (Char)nc;
        if (c == '\0')
        {
            stringsRead.Add(bldr.ToString());
            bldr.Length = 0;
        }
        else
            bldr.Append(c);
    }

    // Optionally return any trailing unterminated string
    if (bldr.Length != 0)
        stringsRead.Add(bldr.ToString());

    return stringsRead;
}
```

Or for reading just one at a time (like ReadLine)

```
string ReadNullTerminated(this System.IO.StreamReader rdr)
{
    var bldr = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    int nc;
    while ((nc = rdr.Read()) > 0)
        bldr.Append((char)nc);

    return bldr.ToString();
}
```