# How to efficiently read a null terminated, non unicode string from unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, performance, unmanaged, null-terminated

I am needing to read a few thousand null terminated C strings from memory.

My current solution is as follows

```
byte* stringPointer; // Obviously has an actual value in my codebase

var stringLength = 0;

while (*(stringPointer + stringLength) != 0x00) 
{
    stringLength += 1;
}

var unmanagedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringPointer, stringLength);
```

This works fine, but I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, considering I am reading thousands of these strings each time this function is called.

Any ideas?

Comment: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string stringPointer`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a null-terminated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713878/reading-a-null-terminated-string)

Comment: _"Any ideas?"_ -- that's pretty much the very definition of "too broad". What is wrong with the code you have now? There are countless different ways you might marshal null-terminated strings from unmanaged memory to managed objects. The best methods will make use of the .NET interop API. _"I am reading thousands of these strings each time this function is called."_ -- and how often do you call that function? 1000's of strings is a cake walk, as a one-time thing. You'd have to be doing it pretty often to be a problem; at that point you should ask whether you need that many strings that often.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, [`Marshal.PtrToStringUTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringutf8?view=netcore-2.0) takes a pointer to a C-style UTF-8 string and returns a managed `string`.

```
var mystring = Marshal.PtrToStringUTF8(stringPointer);
```

That would probably be the most efficient way.

Note that the underlying operation is still *O(N)*, since it involves copying, plus the C# `string` needs to know the length.